# calendar date selection for launching new activity

Tags: android, android-activity, calendarview

Main activity contain action bar with button which display a calendar on same screen. 
I want to launch a new activity when date is selected in the calendar view.
 for that purpose i write the code like this.

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    CalendarView cal;
    String d,m,y;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LinearLayout llAppointment, llAdmitPatient, llAdmitDischarge, lle_counsults, llSecondOpinion, llQandA;
        cal = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calndrView);
        llAppointment = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LLAppointment);
        llAdmitPatient = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LLAdmitPatient);
        llAdmitDischarge = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LLAdmitDischarge);
        lle_counsults = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LLE_consults);
        llSecondOpinion=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LLSecondOpinions);
        llQandA = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LLQandA);


        //appointments 
        llAppointment.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                String Date = df.format(c.getTime());


                 String day=Date.substring(0,2);
                 String month=Date.substring(3,5);
                 String year=Date.substring(8,10);

            d=day;m=month;y=year;

                Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, AllPatientsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("day", day);
                intent.putExtra("month", month);
                intent.putExtra("year", year);

                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });

        // Admitted patients

        llAdmitPatient.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent= new Intent(Main.this, AdmittedPatients.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        // Admit-Discharge
        llAdmitDischarge.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, AdmitDischarge.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        //E-consultant
        lle_counsults.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, EConsultant.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        //Second Opinion
        llSecondOpinion.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, SecondOpinion.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        //Question and answer
        llQandA.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, QAndA.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        cal.setOnDateChangeListener(new OnDateChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year,
                    int month, int day) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        day + "/" + month + "/" + year, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();



                if(Integer.parseInt(d)==day && Integer.parseInt(m)==month && Integer.parseInt(y)==year){
                    Toast.makeText(Main.this, "day:"+day+"d"+d+"month:"+month+"m"+m+"year:"+year+"y"+y, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }


                Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, AllPatientsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("day", day);
                intent.putExtra("month", month);
                intent.putExtra("year", year);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_calendar:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Menu Item 1 selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            cal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

When I press action bar button it should launch calendarView and if i selected a date in that calendar view it should launch second activity showing this date. but problem is that this code does not allow mi to select date other than this month, because as soon as this month changes while scrolling it fires event.
what change should I do in the code so that my new activity will launch with correct date

Comment: you want to start the new Activity when you press on the button in action bar ?

Comment: no no When I press action bar button it should launch calendarView and if i selected a date in that calendar view it should launch second activity showing this date. but problem is that this code does not allow mi to select date other than this month, because as soon as this month changes while scrolling it fires event.

Comment: is it giving any error when you select date other than this month

Comment: no error it launches AllPatientsActivity activity, and we lost a chance to select a date.